# android fetch image from mysql causes app to freeze

Tags: php, android, mysql

I did a school project where i insert image in MySQL on web as blob and i fetch that  image to android app and i set that image to `ImageView` after decode it with `base64` the problem is that this process causes the app to freeze and takes a long time to display it in android , sometime phone does not respond for more than two minutes , i don't know what to do , i have no error in my code neither in `PHP` nor in `Java android` . please help me and tell me what i can do, to display this image faster and efficiently . thanks

php code :

```
  ...
 public function StudentsOfParent($mobile){

 $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT
                         a.id,
                         a.name, 
                         a.mobile, 
                         c.id as sutdentId, 
                         c.user_id, 
                         c.full_name, 
                         c.school, 
                         c.level,
                         c.year,
                         c.photo,
                         d.id as busId,                   
                         d.bus_name as plate_no,
                         e.id as DriverId,                           
                         e.driverphone_number,                          
                         e.driver_fullname                          
                         from users a 
                         join students c 
                         on a.id = c.user_id
                         join buses d 
                         on c.id = d.student_id
                         join drivers e
                         on e.id = d.driver_id where a.mobile= ?");

    $stmt->bind_param("i", $mobile);
if ($stmt->execute()) {    
   $result = $stmt->get_result();
   $usersArr = $result->fetch_all(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
   $stmt->close();
   $result->free(); //Because why not?
   return array_map(function ($user) {
         $user['photo'] = base64_encode($user['photo']);
         return $user;
  }, $usersArr);
 } else {
       return NULL; 
 }
  ...
```

**To access above function:**

```
          ....
       if (isset($_POST['mobile'])){

    $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];

    $usersArr = $db->StudentsOfParent($mobile);
    if ($usersArr != false) { 

      $response["error"]= FALSE;

      $response["user"] = $usersArr;
    echo json_encode($response); 

      .....
```

**Android code used to get image to the interface :**

```
      // login process
     private void GetStudentDetail(final String mobile) {
    // Tag used to cancel the request
    String tag_string_req = "req_Verfication";

    progressBarList.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

         StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST,
                Config.FETCH_StudentsOfParent_URL, new    Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            Log.d(TAG, "cerfication Response: " + response.toString());

              JSONArray jsonArrayResult ;
              for (int i = 0; i < response.length(); i++) {

                try {
                    JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                        boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                        // Check for error node in json
                         if (!error) {

                            jsonArrayResult = jObj.getJSONArray("user");

                            for(int x=0; x<jsonArrayResult.length();x++){

                                JSONObject json = jsonArrayResult.getJSONObject(x);

                                String id = json.getString("id");
                                String studentId = json.getString("sutdentId");
                                 int ID1 =Integer.parseInt(studentId);
                                String full_name = json.getString("full_name");
                                String year = json.getString("year");
                                String school = json.getString("school");
                                String level = json.getString("level");
                                String driver_fullname = json.getString("driver_fullname");
                                String driverphone_number = json.getString("driverphone_number");
                                String plate_no = json.getString("plate_no");

                             // Decode base64_encode encoded image from mysql

                               byte[] photo =  Base64.decode(json.getString("photo"), Base64.DEFAULT) ;
                               Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(photo, 0, photo.length);
                                  image.setImageBitmap(Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, image.getWidth(),
                                        image.getHeight(), false));           

                            }

                          }

                      else{

                        String errorMsg = jObj.getString("error_msg");
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), errorMsg,  Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    }

                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                      // JSON error
                    e.printStackTrace();
                     Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Json error: " +     e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                 }
            }
          }
            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Log.e(TAG, "Verfication error Error: " + error.getMessage());          
        }
       }) {

        @Override
        protected Map<String, String> getParams() {

            Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put("mobile", mobile);
            return params;
        }
    };
   // Adding request to request queue

    MyApplication.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(strReq,tag_string_req);
}
```

Comment: Don't store images in the database... store files on filesystem

Comment: @B001b thnx so please can you provide me an example

Comment: _provide me an example.._ what example? Store your images on file system, get the path(url) and show images by linking to the url...

Comment: @B001 thanks. i was thinking that is going to be more complicate , for example when i want to so  select a specific image of such user,  `select image  where id=$user`

Comment: I am not talking about databases.. I'd recommend to store the user id etc into db and just store files on filesystem (just like images on your own pc)